# Crontab is not using PATH written in /etc/environment

Tags: cron, environment-variables

I am loading environment variables to crontab by writting those variables in `/etc/environment`. One of the variables I need to use is `PATH`. Although I am writting the `PATH` to the `/etc/enviroment` I see that cron uses another value of `PATH` still.

My `/etc/environemnt`:

```
# cat /etc/environment
...
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
...
```

The output of cron when it logs the output of `env`

```
...
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
...
```

I managed to solve the issue by hardcoding the desired `PATH` to the cron job file, however I would prefer writing the `PATH` dynamically based on the actual `PATH`